# Copy file from Azure VM to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-virtual-machine

Am new to this and am trying to do something which I think is relatively simple.

I download a file from a URL to my Azure VM using wget (its a large file and I don't want to store it locally). I want to now copy this file to an existing container in blob storage. This is completely defeating me.

It's a single line command in the aws universe

```
aws s3 sync <file_name> s3://<bucket name>
```

is there an equivalent in azure?

Comment: Actually that's the other unexpected thing - the VM doesn't seem to have Azure CLI. Next best option seems to be to do it through Azure Cloud Shell where at least the CLI exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways by you can accomplish this and you don't even have to download this large file on your local computer first and then upload in blob storage.

For example, you can use [`az storage blob copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/copy?view=azure-cli-latest) command which is part of Azure CLI tools, to do so. Here's the sample command for that:

```
az storage blob copy start --account-key <your-azure-storage-account-key> --account-name <your-azure-storage-account-name> --destination-blob <name-of-the-blob> --destination-container <name-of-the-container> --source-uri <uri-of-the-file>
```

You can also accomplish the same using [`azcopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json) utility or [`Azure PowerShell Storage Cmdlets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/?view=azps-3.8.0). The Cmdlet you would want to use is [`Start-AzStorageBlobCopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/Start-AzStorageBlobCopy?view=azps-3.8.0).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't see Azure CLI installed on the azure VM. 
And the azcopy documentation doesn't seem to allow for VM -> storage 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json

That leaves Azure Cloud Shell, which presumably is my best bet.

Comment: You’ll need to install them on the VM or on your local computer. You can run these command from your local computer as well.