# How to copy .HTML reports from azure web app to azure blob storage

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines

I'm unable to upload reports in blob storage.

I tried azcopy, copy files, Azurecli and python script, but it won't work.

In my reports are stored in inside webapp /home/wwwroot location and I move to blob container after that all reports are working in single endpoint through apim

Comment: Can you update your question with the code or script you tried with azcopy and azureCLI?, for me to test on my end Also, Did you try to make use of kudu console > to run az copy command and copy the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Kudu console and install Azure CLI or Az copy tool and run the command inside the console to copy the reports from your Web app site/wwwroot to your blob storage given you are giving correct connection string to your Storage account.

***Visit > Azure Web app > Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go > SSH or Bash > and run the commands below:-***

[image]

```bash
wget -O azcopy_v10.tar.gz https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v10-linux && tar -xf azcopy_v10.tar.gz --strip-components=1
```

**SSH console:-**

[image]

**Bash console:-**

[image]

**And then run this command:-**

```bash
azcopy cp "LogFiles" "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/LogFiles??sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&spxxx1xxx:06:01Z&spr=https&sig=xxxxexxD"
```

You can make use of **Azure CLI command to copy the file, First install Azure CLI** like below:-

```bash
apt-get install azure-cli
```

[image]

Then **run:-**

> ```
> az storage blob copy start --account-key <your-azure-storage-account-key> --account-name <your-azure-storage-account-name> --destination-blob <name-of-the-blob> --destination-container <name-of-the-container> --source-uri <uri-of-the-file>
> ```

**References:-**

[Copy file from Azure VM to Azure Blob Storage - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61592539/copy-file-from-azure-vm-to-azure-blob-storage) By Gaurav Mantri

[Copy or move data to Azure Storage by using AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10)